A solution to a diffrential equation is always below the line y=t
Points on the plane are moving according to the law described by the equation $\dot{x} = t^{2024} - x^{2024}$. Note that its solution cannot be expressed by the means of elementary functions. Let $\varphi : [1, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a solution emitting from the point $(1, 0)$ (i.e., $\varphi(1) = 0$). Prove that it stays below the line ${x = t}$.
What I have tried:
By way of contradiction, assume there exists $t_0$ such that $\varphi(t_0) = t_0$ (let it be the first such $t_0$). Thus, we get using our formula of motion that $\varphi'(t_0) = 0$.
Another thing I noticed is that I am sure that $\varphi'(t_0) >= 1$ as well  by our assumption, since how could it get to the line $y=t$ if it starts on $(1,0)$ and $y=t$ starts on $(1,1)$ it must somehow "accelerate fast enough" to catch on. but I didn't manage to show that. I am not sure how to show that as well. I did manage to show that $\varphi(t)<t$ for all $[1,t_0]$.
Much help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Your intuition is correct. You can use contradiction to prove it.
Namely, let $t_0>1$ be the first time when  $\phi(t_0)=t_0$. Then from the ODE you have $\phi'(t_0)=0$. In a left neighborhood of $t_0$, by continuity of $\phi'$ you have $|\phi'(t)|<1/2$ and therefore, $\phi(t)>t$ in that left neighborhood. By the intermediate value theorem, there would exist some $t_1\in (1,t_0)$ where $\phi(t_1)=t_1$, contradicting the definition of $t_0$.

why does   |ϕ′(t)|<1/2
imply, ϕ(t)>t ?

Intuitively, at the point of intersection $\phi$ has a slope close to zero (between $-1/2$ and $1/2$) and therefore it is above $x=t$  for $t<t_0$ and below $x=t$ for $t>t_0$, at least locally.

I understand the intuition, but how do I show it using the algebra?

You do not know the nature of your potential solution, so you need a more “qualitative “ reasoning. In this case, it is a consequence of continuity, just the definition. There is no “algebraic way” to do it.

using lagrange and the fact that |ϕ′(t)|<1/2
implies, ϕ(t)<t/2 -1/2. so how does it help me?

I think I might have it.
$\varphi'(t_0) = \lim_{t \to t_0^-} \frac{\varphi(t) - \varphi(t_0)}{t - t_0} = \lim_{t \to t_0^-} \frac{\varphi(t) - t_0}{t - t_0} = \lim_{t \to t_0^-} \frac{t_0 - \varphi(t)}{t_0 - t} > \lim_{t \to t_0^-} \frac{t_0 - t}{t_0 - t} = 1.$

There is no way around the continuity argument. Once you have that, you just compare the integrals of $1$ and $\phi’$ between $t$ and $t_0$ with $t$ in the neighborhood.

That's  true, but I think what I showed is enough, isn't it? I just showed that φ′(t0)>1 but we also have from the ODE that φ′(t0)=0, thus a contradiction.

Not quite.  How do you know that $\phi’(t_0)>1$? It could cross “tangentially “ with $\phi’(t_0)=1$.

what I wrote isn't enough? (I mean, the inequality that I did with the limit isnt correct?, I manage to show that ϕ(t)<t (strictly less) so it goes to be strictly bigger. Also even ϕ′(t0)=1 works since it still contradicts the fact that ϕ′(t0)=0 from the ODE

Yes, the contradiction is correct. But what you can actually prove is the weaker statement $\phi’(t_0)\ge 1$ .
